# What are minimum requirement to show any content with styling on browser?

Tags: css, xhtml, web-standards, semantic-markup

What are minimum requirement to show any content with styling on browser?

My one curious friend who is learning about html and css asked some questions to me.with example. ( I uploaded his example page to my hosting)

1. What are minimum requirement to show any content with styling on browser?
2. Why this page is working with styling? see this page : http://jitendravyas.com/testing/html.html 
   This page is giving different output in different browsers. I checked in IE, Firefox google chrome and all are rendering outer border differently.
3. What are cons to not to use Doctype for SEO?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Doctype is not just for SEO, it's for basic standards. The browser needs to know the doctype just as much (if not more) as search engines do.

Comment: In your example you need to add more markup to help browsers read the code properly. 
After that you'll need to add some form of CSS reset, which is a starting point for making styles work across different browsers

Comment: @graham - That I know. my questions is different

Answer (score 1):

- What are minimum requirement to show any content with styling on browser?

Exactly what you have. But this will obviously not look the same in different browsers

- Why this page is working with styling?

Why wouldn't it?

- What are cons to not to use Doctype for SEO?

The real question is why do you think not using a doctype is good for SEO? It isn't. Use a valid doctype.